# Let $f : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ and $A_2$ a sigma field on $\Omega_2$. Show that $f^{-1}(A_2)$ is a sigma field on $\Omega_1$.

Tags: statistics

Let $f : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ be a mapping from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$. Further, let $A_2$ be sigma field on $\Omega_2$. Show that the preimage $f^{−1}(A_2)$ is always a sigma field on $\Omega_1$.

Hints: • $\forall B \in A_1: (f^{-1}(B))^c = f^{−1}(B^c)$.

• $\forall B_1, B_2, \dots \in A_2: \bigcup_n f^{−1}(B_n) = f^{−1}\left ( \bigcup_n Bn\right )$.

Comment: What happens when you use the definitions and try to prove this?  Without your efforts, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Does anyone solve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to this page. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem and looks like a homework question. Please let us know what you tried, what you know and where you struggle, what the definitions are that you know and so on.
On top of that, try to use MathJax formatting to make the questions look nicer. See a tutorial here:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Shohel Sure, but if you ask in this way it is unlikely that a solution will be presented to you. Please use MathJax (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) and most of all show your efforts ( see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question))